# Set dynamic line break in an Android TextView

Tags: android

I have a TextView where I show an e-mail that I take from JsonObject.

If this e-mail is too long it will use a second line for a single character too.
For example:

> example.email@email.co
> m

To avoid it I would like to put a line break in those cases in which I have more lines

> example.email@email
> .com

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea what i can try.

Comment: Beware, your question might be flagged as too general in that case. Also, this is a pretty complex task, but I can't find a valid use case for it. You might be able to solve your client's problem by using another approach, like setting your TextView's "ellipsize" attribute to "end" or "marquee".